# i want to add a location search bar to get delivery charges added accordingly for a single city

Tags: android, google-maps

I am building an android app for food delivery for a particular city. I want to add different delivery charges for different locations of the city. for that I want to build and 'choose your location' search bar. Please help me.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. my life depends in this app please help

Comment: `my life depends in this app` sounds kinda **exagerate**.

Comment: haha kind of...career is life

Comment: hm, no. Career is career. Life is life.

Comment: Don't be dramatic - use Place Autocomplete - https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

I think solution to your problem is the use of Place Autocomplete, it provides you both a fragment option to use within your activity, or you can call Autocomplete activity with intent. You can find directions on how to implement this [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete). And don't be dramatic - life is life, and even black piano keys make the music :)